# Sort "Open Files" in sidebar by alphabetical order?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is there any way to sort the "Open Files" section in the sidebar by alphabetical order?

[image]

Answer (score 12):

The open files section of the sidebar is listed in the same order as the open tabs in the editor, so you can alphabetize the list by alphabetizing the tabs.

There is a plugin called [SortTabs](https://github.com/bizoo/SortTabs) that will do this automatically. It also has a couple of other sorting options, including sorting by file type and last modified date.

Comment: Hmm, what if I have switched off tabs?

Answer (score 2):

sortTabs is the way to go as pointed out by Derrick. I would like to add, opening more than one instance of the same file, will not let the linter to work properly. sortTabs helps identify those duplicate instances. Although, written for Sublime Text 2, sortTabs also works well in ST3. Ctrl+Shift+P > sortTabs Menu > choose your sorting criteria.